# angularjs view is loaded before resolve checks access

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm setting up an access control system in angular. This is how it looks so far.
It's doing the ajax to return the current user's role, then checking that role with the access array to see if the user has permission. If not it redirects.

That all works fine, but the view is still being shown for a split second before the redirect.

It may also be important to note that the ajax request is necessary because the user auth is being handled with Laravel, so I made an API for Angular to talk to get information about the user's session.

```
var app = angular.module('application', ['ngResource']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/admin', {
            controller: 'showAdmin',
            templateUrl: 'admin.html',
            access: ['Admin', 'Manager'],
            resolve: AppCtrl.resolve
        });
});

function AppCtrl ($scope, getUser, $location, $rootScope) {

}

AppCtrl.resolve = {
    getUser : function($q, $http, $location, $rootScope) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/getUser'
        })
        .success(function(data, status) {
            $rootScope.user = data;
            if($rootScope.access.indexOf(data.permissions[0].role_name) < 0) $location.path('/');
        });
    }
};

app.run(function ($rootScope, sessionFactory, $location){
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
        $rootScope.access = next.access;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an [ng-cloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak#!) directive on the containing element to eliminate the flicker.  See [this page](http://ng-model.com/category/angularjs/) for an example along with some CSS/browser-specific gotchas.

Comment: That's what I was going to try, but I was a little concerned that maybe this isn't the most secure method.

Comment: Using the ng-cloak directive, along with CSS `display:none !important` resolves your view concern, and the security concern should remain separate.  Also, instead of rolling your own hooks to get Laravel into the Angular lifecycle, consider something from [ngmodules.org](http://ngmodules.org/).

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. I'm not seeing a flash of the Angular brackets, I'm seeing a flash of the rendered page with the data there. I did try the ng-cloak, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Do you have a plunkr or jsFiddle to repro the issue?